# Selenium iframes problems

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, iframe, selenium-chromedriver

I'am using Selenium with C#, i have a problem with iframe.

I'm trying to make a comment but once i open the comment section of a thread, i can't interact with the components. I know there is iframe and maybe nested iframes. So for i tried:

```
var iframeList = d.FindElements(By.TagName("iframe"));
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(String.Format(@"{0}\iframe.txt", f.GetFolderPath())))
{
    foreach(IWebElement element in iframeList)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(element);
    }                           
}
```

this part of code below give me this result inside my txt file:

```
Element (id = 10f1b5bf-a2ce-4ffe-92a6-d2dc8e55bf5a)
```

**note that the id above change each time i try to run the code and sometime there is 2 differents id**

also when i inspect the webpage element(F12), the iframe id="here is the id" constantly change each time i run my code.

So for switching the iframe, i did this:

```
var iframeList = d.FindElements(By.TagName("iframe"));
IWebElement[] iframeArr = iframeList.ToArray();
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(String.Format(@"{0}\iframe.txt", f.GetFolderPath())))
{
    for(int j = 0; j < iframeArr.Length; j++)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(iframeArr[j].ToString()); //write to file
    }                           
}

d.SwitchTo().Frame(iframeArr[0]);
```

code above seem to switch to an iframe but still can't access components of the page.

I also tried switching with nested iframes:

```
var iframeList = d.FindElements(By.TagName("iframe"));
IWebElement[] iframeArr = iframeList.ToArray();
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(String.Format(@"{0}\iframe.txt", f.GetFolderPath())))
{
    for(int j = 0; j < iframeArr.Length; j++)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(iframeArr[j].ToString()); //write to file
    }                           
}

d.SwitchTo().Frame(iframeArr[0]);
d.SwitchTo().Frame(iframeArr[1]);
```

Code above also don't work.

Some other examples i tried with no results:

```
d.SwitchTo().Frame(d.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/iframe")));
//Dont work

d.SwitchTo().Frame(d.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[@class='GTM-5XVNS82']")));
//Dont work

d.SwitchTo().Frame((IWebElement)wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.
ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.TagName("iframe"))));
//Dont work

var iframe = d.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[src*='https://www.redditmedia.com/gtm/jail? 
id=GTM-5XVNS82']"));
//Dont work

d.SwitchTo().Frame(0);
//Dont work

d.SwitchTo().Frame(0);
d.SwitchTo().Frame(1);
//Dont work
```

I also tried numerous other methods and still no succes. I can't copy the code as it look like in the google inspect so i made a screenshot of the iframe code:
[image]

Sry for the code in the screenshot i tried to copy the code but it just dont work properly.

Hope someone can give me an hand its been days i'm on this problem and i absolutely don't know what to do at this point.

Thank you!

Comment: There are nested iframes for the area you're looking at - but are you sure you're looking in the right location?   ....  I've looked at reddit and i can't see and reason you need to be in there. The comments field is available outside the iframes.    Can you please update your question 1) with a link of the page you're looking at  2) add a few words (more specifically) about what and where you're clicking  and also 3) clarify "dont work", is there an error? - normally the errors tells you what's wrong

Comment: @RichEdwards thx for your reply, its really appreciated! I found the way: var comment = wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//div[@class='public-DraftStyleDefault-block public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr']")));
                                comment.SendKeys(m.Comments());